# MKL Matrix Transpose

Tags: c, c++11, intel, intel-mkl

I have a very large rectangular and square float as well as complex matrix. I want to know Is there any in place MKL transpose routine? There is mkl_?imatcopy in MKL, please help me with an example.

I have tried this, but it didnot transpose matrix

```
    size_t nEle = noOfCols * noOfRows;
    float *data = (float*)calloc(nEle,sizeof(float));
    initalizeData(data,noOfCols,noOfRows);
    printdata(data,noOfCols,noOfRows);
    printf("After transpose \n\n");
    mkl_simatcopy('R','T',noOfCols,noOfRows,1,data,noOfPix,noOfCols); 
    //writeDataFile((char *)data,"AfterTranspose.img",nEle*sizeof(float));
    printdata(data,noOfCols,noOfRows);
```

Comment: Have a look at `imatcopy` (in place), not `omatcopy` (out of place). https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-mkl-imatcopy The usage example is part of the MKL distribution.

Comment: size_t nEle = noOfCols * noOfRows;

        float *data = (float *)calloc(nEle,sizeof(float));
        initalizeData(data,noOfScan,noOfPix);
        printdata(data,noOfScan,noOfPix);
        //writeDataFile((char *)data,"BeforeTranspose.img",nEle*sizeof(float));
        printf("After transpose \n\n");
        mkl_simatcopy('R','T',noOfScan,noOfPix,1,data,noOfPix,noOfScan); 
        //writeDataFile((char *)data,"AfterTranspose.img",nEle*sizeof(float));
        printdata(data,noOfScan,noOfPix);

Comment: What is `noOfPix`? Also, it seems you are swapping rows and columns. I have not tested, but, for a row major matrix, allocated of exact size (as you did), I think the call should be: `mkl_simatcopy('R','T',noOfRows,noOfCols,1,data,noOfCols,noOfRows)`

Answer (score 0):

You may try to look at the existing in-place transposition routines for float real and complex datatypes. MKL package contains such examples: cimatcopy.c dimatcopy.c simatcopy.c zimatcopy.c. Please refer to the mklroot/examples/transc/source directory

Comment: Could you add one such an example?